# ImpEx Import of Arabic Text

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I am trying an impex import in Hybris Administration Console to add arabic text for some products.

The arabic text is in UTF-16 LE format and English text is in UTF-8 format. Therefore, I am always getting an error:

```
{1=ValueEntry('عدّة البدء Single'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=false)}] - cannot import, unknown type '1234546' in line ValueLine 

[,line 3 at main script,1234546,HeaderDescriptor[line 2 at main script, insert_update, Product, {}, [code, endUserShort]}
```

I tried setting my scrip encoding as UTF 16 LE, after which editor can not recognize the english text and produces same error.

Here is my code:

```
$productCatalog=Master
$catalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$productCatalog]),version[default='Master'])

insert_update Product;code[unique=true]; endUserShort[lang=ar_Arab]

1234546;    عدّة البدء Single
```

Any suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `;` on the beginning of your impex should be like this i think :

```
$productCatalog=Master
$catalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$productCatalog]),version[default='Master'])

insert_update Product;code[unique=true]; endUserShort[lang=ar_Arab];$catalogVersion

;1234546;    عدّة البدء Single
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I added ; before 123456 but it still didn't worked. To me it seems 2 languages encoding issue with UTF 8 & UTF 16 LE.

Comment: `insert_update Product;code[unique=true];endUserShort[lang=ar_AR]
1234546,,,,unknown type '1234546' in line ValueLine[,line 7 at main script,1234546,HeaderDescriptor[line 5 at main script, insert_update, Product, {}, [code, endUserShort] ],{1=ValueEntry('عدّة البدء Single'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=false)}] - cannot import, unknown type '1234546' in line ValueLine[,line 3 at main script,1234546,HeaderDescriptor[line 2 at main script, insert_update, Product, {}, [code, endUserShort] ],{1=ValueEntry('عدّة البدء Single'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=false)}] - cannot import;عدّة البدء Single`

Comment: I just executed a similar impex, without `;` at the beginning, I had the same error, but it worked well when I added it, btw shouldn't you use `$productCatalog` on your impex header? @user2742934

Comment: The code validation is correct in debug mode but it does not run in my hybris management console. I always gets same error as mentioned. Unsure about Internal Hybris encoding techniques.

Comment: Could you please reimport the latest impex script i just updated in my answer ? @user2742934